# Looping Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

How do I make this:

```
*******
-*****-
--***--
---*---
--***--
-*****-
*******
```

The following is my code that I have written to try to accomplish the above, but it is not working as expected:

```
    public static void stars(/*int jmlBaris*/) {
    for ( int i = 7; i >= 1; i-=2) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i+=2) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
            }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    stars();
}
}
```

Comment: Since this is not tagged as c++ anymore I removed my solution. It would help if you break the function up. Having one large function make it hard to solve a problem sometimes. Also, consider a recursive solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I might write it.

```
// three loops
public static void stars(int size) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < y && i < size - y - 1; i++)
            System.out.print(' ');
        for (int i = Math.min(y, size - y - 1); i < Math.max(y + 1, size - y); i++)
            System.out.print('*');
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or

```
// two loops
public static void stars(int size) {
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            System.out.print(
                    (x >= y && x < size - y) ||
                            (x >= size - y - 1 && x <= y) ? '*' : ' ');
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

or

```
// one loop
public static void stars(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
        int y = i / size, x = i % size;
        System.out.print(
                (x >= y && x < size - y) ||
                        (x >= size - y - 1 && x <= y) ? '*' : ' ');
        if (x == size - 1)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Note: Whether this uses one, two or three loops, the time complexity is O(N^2).  A simple way to determine this is the number of stars produced is O(N^2) no matter how it is done.

Comment: sorry, i can't even print this algorithm D:

Comment: Do you mean you have trouble compiling/running it? It prints the expected output in you give it the size of 7.

Comment: ya, running it, already make psvm but it says erroneous sym type=stars,

Comment: I can't imagine what you are doing wrong.  It's a simple static method call with one argument. `stars(7);` in your main.

Comment: worked now hehe thanks, can you explain this Math.min(y, size - y - 1); i < Math.max(y + 1, size - y); ? i didn't get it, just 2 days i learn java things . still confused at logic-.-

Comment: Imagine you are drawing a X on paper with \ and /. The `y` represents the \ and the `size - y - 1` represents the /.  You want the X to start with the smallest of those values (min) and end with the largest (max)

Comment: about that `Math`  thingy. is that unchangable?

Comment: @alexkirkland It is a built in class which won't change between versions of Java if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this with substrings.

```
String a = "*******";  //7 stars
String blank = "        "; //7 spaces
int j = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (i > j){
        System.out.print(blank.substring(0,i));
        System.out.println(a.substring(i,j));
        }
    else{
        System.out.print(blank.substring(0,j));
        System.out.println(a.substring(j,i));
        }
    j--;
}
System.out.println(a);
```

**Previous edit wouldn't have worked. Changes made.

This works.

Comment: This is not very generic, first of all your hard coding the values.

Comment: True... A variable could be passed to the method as an integer for a for-statement to generate the length for String a. Then that variable could be used in the for-statement for i's bound and j as well.

Comment: This is not very generic, first of all your hard coding the values, also using substring is totally unnecessary here, extra overhead. This is a very simple school level program and can be done using loops.

Comment: I don't think such a simple program will need to use substrings and its overhead - it could be done much easier with loops and characters instead.

Comment: @alexkirkland A substring is a string that came from another string. For example, with the string `Hello world!`, if we took the substring 0, 5 (Meaning take 5 characters from the 0th place of the string), we'll end up with a substring returned: `Hello`. More info here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this code I compiled on IDEOne (it seems to work, though):
http://ideone.com/9xZ1YB

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        stars();
    }

    static void stars()
    {
        final int MAX_WIDTH = 7;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        {
            int width;

            if (i < 3) width = MAX_WIDTH - i * 2;
            else if (i > 3) width = (i - 3) * 2 + 1;
            else width = 1;

            // Before spaces

            for (int j = 0; j < (MAX_WIDTH - width) / 2; ++j)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            // Stars

            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            // After spaces

            for (int j = 0; j < (MAX_WIDTH - width) / 2; ++j)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's actually printing a newline :) maybe those should be `print` calls.

Comment: Edited, dang, missed that out.

Comment: @alexkirkland That's because when it's printing out vertically the space was invisible to you.

Comment: without println the output became like this ******* ***** *** * * *** ***** *******  -.-

Comment: nah sorry , with println, it makes new line :D if replace println become print, there is no new line there

Comment: Ack, sorry, I totally misunderstood the post. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: that's worked, but is it possible not using if else? i got no idea what's the meaning your if else condition ahaha

Comment: Oh, ok. `i < 3` meant the ones before the middle star, `i > 3` were the ones after, while anything else, `i == 3`, is just 1 in width.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21397/discussion-between-alexkirkland-and-yoshi-hi)

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner in algorithms I would recommend you to break down the structure in sub-parts and then try to solve the pattern.

For this specific pattern it could be broken down into several triangles. Each triangle is then solved by different `for` loops as shown in the image below.

[image: dividing the pattern into substructures]

```
public static void printPattern(int num) {
    // this loop generates first 4 lines
    for (int i = 0; i < num / 2 + 1; i++) {
        // draws the red triangle of '-'
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        // draws the green triangle of '*'
        for (int j = i; j < num / 2 + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // draws the blue triangle of '*'
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num / 2 + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // draws the orange triangle of '-'
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /* this loop generates last 3 lines */
    for (int i = 0; i < num / 2; i++) {
        // draws the green triangle of '-'
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num / 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        // draws the red triangle of '*'
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // draws the orange triangle of '*'
        for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        // draws the blue triangle of '-'
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num / 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Using similar technique you could generate any pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, your problem is to print indent in lines 2-7.

Imagine same problem with asterisk symbol replaced by 'x' and whitespace replaced by '-'. Then you need to draw

```
xxxxxxx
-xxxxx-
--xxx--
---x---
--xxx--
-xxxxx-
xxxxxxx
```

That means you should output 0, 1, 2 space(s) before asterisks in first, second, thrid strings respectively. I let details for you to figure them out.

Comment: I suspect the white space at the end of the line is optional.

Comment: ya, must be like that, i'm confused at '-' and how to make x in line 4 just 1,

Comment: @PeterLawrey, definetly! It've included it for symmetry only.

Comment: @alexkirkland, you can count number of '-' in every line and find a formula for it. I'd suggest you to do it by yourself. It's a good brain-teaser for a beginner in algorithms.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe , ya i must do it by myself, that's why i ask  someone to explain how to make the '-' using looping,

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void stars(/*int jmlBaris*/){
    String starstr = "*";
    String blank = "_";
    int spaceBlank;;
    for(int i=7; i>=1;i-=2){
        spaceBlank = (7-i)*.5;
        String starrep = StringUtils.repeat(starstr, i);
        String blankrep = StrinUtils.repeat(blank, spacesBlank);
        system.out.println(blankrep + starrep + blankrep);
    }
    for(int j=3 j<=7; j+=2){
        spaceBlank = (7-j)*.5;
        starrep = StringUtils.repeat(starstr, j);
         String blankrep = StrinUtils.repeat(blank, spacesBlank);
        system.out.println(blankrep + starrep  + blankrep);
    }
}    
public static void main(String[] args){
    stars();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about that site I will definitely be using it, but my employer is blocks everything productive.  Cant access that site from here.

Answer (score 0):

You have little missing to put space on your code. I don't care about right space, who can see that? But left space is very important!!

Try this:

```
public static void stars(/*int jmlBaris*/) {
    for ( int i = 7; i >= 1; i-=2) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ((7-i) / 2); k++){ /* Missing Here */
            System.out.print(" "); /* Missing Here */
        } /* Missing Here */

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i+=2) {
        for (int k = 0; k < ((7-i) / 2); k++){ /* Missing Here */
            System.out.print(" "); /* Missing Here */
        } /* Missing Here */

        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int N = 7;
    for (int y=0; y<N; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<N; x++)
            System.out.print( (y-x)*(N-y-x-1)<=0 ? '*' : '-');
        System.out.println();
    }
```

or, more symmetrically,

```
    int n = 3;
    for (int y=-n; y<=n; y++)
    {
        for (int x=-n; x<=n; x++)
            System.out.print( y*y>=x*x ? '*' : '-');
        System.out.println();
    }
```